# How can I call a method from html attribute in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a form and I need to call a method from a placeholder and also from other types of html attribute.

Is there anyways I can call a vue method? 
Here is what I am trying to do

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="user.userName" 
 placeholder=t("un") required> // want to call method t() from the placeholder
```

It seems this method cannot be called this way. Is there any other ways to achieve this?

And my method is

```
methods: {
   t(key){
        console.log(key)
        var local='fr';
        return this.trans(key,local);
      }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by calling a method from placeholder? Maybe you want computed properties?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. It is not an event. I am trying to call a method `t()` which is declared inside my `methods` from the `placeholder` attribute

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: Do you want to translate your placeholder?

Comment: yes and translation logic is defined in the t() method.

Comment: You can use [i18n plugin](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `v-bind` (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind)

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="user.userName" 
 v-bind:placeholder="t('un')" required>
```

Comment: Great, I tried everything except `''` single quotation :)

Comment: @sadek ah, yes. You cannot nest `"` inside `"` without escaping them. The alternative is to use the `'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="user.userName" :placeholder="t('un')" required>
```